# Comparing values using hashtable

Tags: java, key, hashtable

There is a table like:

```
Code(starts with)     Value
1                       AAA
101D                    BBB
101DG                   CCC
2                       DDD
```

The above table has the columns code and corresponding values. The Code column signifies the string starts with the code given and on comparing it with the input code of the user, the corresponding value will be assigned from value column of table.

For example:

- if the user's code is 100000, then value should be AAA......
- For user's code 101D1111, value should be BBB(not AAA even if this starts with 1 as we will consider more significant comparison which is with 101D)......
- For user's code as 101DG222, value should be CCC(not BBB even if it starts with 101D   as we will notice the most significant comparison).....
- For user cose 23333, value=DDD.....

I have put the following table in a hashtable with key as code column and value as value column.

```
HashTable hash= new HashTable();
hash.put("1","AAA");
hash.put("101D","BBB");
hash.put("101DG","CCC");
hash.put("2","DDD");

String comp="101D1111";//string to compare

Iterator itr= hash.entrySet().iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())
{
   Map.Entry e=(Map.Entry)itr.next();

  String key=  (String).getKey();

   //**Here logic is needed to compare comp and key and retrieve the corrsponding    value here as BBB**


}
```

Kindly help me with this logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to first sort your entries by key length, with the longest ones being first and the shortest ones last. Because you first want to check whether your Code starts with `101DG`, and only then check whether it starts with `101DG` and finally `1`.

Then to check for matches you could use something like this:

```
if (comp.substring(0,key.length()).equals(key)) {
    // it's a match — use this Value
}
```

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried, and we will help you fix it. To get you started, have a look at `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a `HashTable` is a good data structure for this purpose, since if you are iterating over all the entries, what's the point of having a `HashTable`?

A better structure (which would take more work to implement, though) is a tree. Each node of the tree would represent a prefix and the value associated with it :

For example, this is how the tree would look for your example:

```
             ROOT
           /      \
         1 (AAA)   2 (DDD)
           |
           10
            |
           101
           /
        101D (BBB)
          |
        101DG (CCC)
```

Now, for a given user code, you start traversing the tree from the ROOT, each time following the child node that holds the next character of the user code. You stop when you don't find any child node that matches. Each node you visit, you take the value stored in it. You return the last value you find.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still not versed with complex data structures that are present then,this simple solution will help you

```
String keySearch=new String();
String val=null;
for(i=0;i<comp.length();i++){
    keySearch+=comp.charAt(i);
    if(table.contains(keySearch)){
        val=map.get(keySearch);
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

but using a  HashTable is not really efficient  in this case

Comment: In actual sense, my key will be like this: "001,IND,9,101D".....so I have to get the tokens separated by comma and compare 101D as one block and "001,IND,9" as one block and "101D" as second entity....kindly give me the solution according to this

Comment: but you just have to check if the start of your 'comp' string matches with some particular key that you have in your table.
Am I correct?

Comment: Your question doesn't specify this requirement,but if you want to use "101D" as one block and "001,IND,9" as other,you should have different separators e.g"001/IND/09,101D" so that you can easily identify your blocks,hope you are getting it

Comment: yes Vihar....I will use slash / as identifiers to separate the tokens....So, how to compare , so that I get the value column after comparison of 1st block of 101D and second block together in one IF statement?

Comment: here at stackoverflow only help wil be provided,you will have to find a way to handle some small issues,this is how you will learn, please try once and if you still dont get it,we are happy to help!
happy learning!

Comment: Sorry Dear, got a little busy in stuff, bcoz of that I am late to reply....but really Bro thanks a lot , this thread helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Below code would do the trick. You could also use Generics in the iterator to make the code type safe.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;


public class TestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

HashMap hash= new HashMap<String, String>();


hash.put("1","AAA");
hash.put("101D","BBB");
hash.put("101DG","CCC");
hash.put("2","DDD");

String comp="101D1111";//string to compare

Iterator itr= hash.entrySet().iterator();

String value = null;
int length = 0;
while(itr.hasNext())
{
   Map.Entry e=(Map.Entry)itr.next();

   if(comp.startsWith(((String)e.getKey())) && ((String)e.getKey()).length() > length) {
       value = (String)e.getValue();
       length = ((String)e.getKey()).length();         
   }

   //**Here logic is needed to compare comp and key and retrieve the corrsponding    value here as BBB**


}
System.out.println(value);
}
```

}